# Incompatible types in assignments of 'float*' to 'float* [1000]'

Tags: c++

```
float a[1000];
float b[1000];
float c[1000];

int main()
{
    float *w1;
    w1 = &a;
    float *w2[1000];
    w2 = &b;
    ...
}
```

so error: cannot convert `float (*)[1000]` to `float*` in assignments - to `w1`
and compiler throws error: incompatible types in assignments of `float*` to `float * [1000]` to `w2`

Comment: Please be careful by reporting exact errors: it is likely that it was spelt _assignments_ instead of _assigments_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you aim to do something like this?

```
float a[1000];
float b[1000];
float c[1000];

int main()
{
    float *w1;
    w1 = a;    // no need of &
    float *w2; // no need of [1000]
    w2 = b;    // no need of &

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you, I'm learning so sorry for my inattention

Answer (score 1):

```
float *w2[1000];
```

is erroneous, and should be `float *w2;`

```
float a[1000];
float b[1000];
float c[1000];

int main()
{
float *w1;
w1 = a;
float *w2;
w2 = b; 
}
```

compiles with no error.

The '&' is intended for single variables, not arrays of single variables. When you instantiate an array with `[]` your variable actually transforms into a pointer.

Comment: Happens to this two cases so it gives same error to w1 and w2

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you, I'm learning so sorry for my inattention